# Overlap integral betwen two Hagedorn function s

Tags: calculus

Hier is my problem.
I'm working in  quntum molecular dynamics. I'm trying to solve a problem which lead me to a resolution on an integral, an i don't no how to proceed.
suppose that we have two hagedorn shifted functions define as:
$$\phi_{k}=\sqrt(\frac{a1}{k! 2^k\sqrt\pi})H_{k}[a1(x- x1)]\exp[-\frac{1}{2}a1^2(x- x1)^2+i\times p1(x-x1)]$$;
$$\phi_{l}=\sqrt(\frac{a2}{l! 2^l\sqrt\pi})H_{l}[a2(x- x1)]\exp[-\frac{1}{2}a2^2(x- x1)^2+i\times p1(x-x1)]$$; H stand for Hermite polynomial and $i=\sqrt-1$ the complex number
I want to evaluate the overlap function $S(k,l)=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\phi_{k}\phi_{l}$. I tried to do so numerically  by using Gauss quadrature and it need more grid points to give accurate solution. So my problem is that i want the analytical solution and i don't no haw to proceed.